# "Answer similar questions" search lists the original question

Tags: bug, search, answer-similar-questions

I've just been offered the "Answer similar questions" button after answering a question. I clicked it, and the resulting search included the question I've just answered (at about 5th position from top). I just thought I'd report this, as it doesn't seem right.

Comment: That whole *thing* doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: I can see question on 2nd position. Probably, can get rid of the question which is just answered to from the list.

Comment: @Rikesh Removing the answered question is *the* fix I would expect.

Comment: Maybe the system determined that your original answer wasn't good enough. Maybe it wants another answer out of you.

Comment: Mine was first. I didn't think my answer was *that* bad.

Comment: This [also happens](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287079/1591669) when the question is the *only* "similar" one.